# Asynchronous loading - UITableView and Firebase

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase

I'm working on a project that loads list data from Firebase and populates a UITableView. While I see the snapshots being called from my firebase instance, they don't populate the table, while a local synchronous, NSMutableArray shows content. How do I make my UITableView wait for the firebase data to get there?

Here's the code:

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    handles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Item No. 1", @"Item No. 2", @"Item No. 3", @"Item No. 4", @"Item No. 5", @"Item No. 6", nil];
    [self loadDataFromFirebase];
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[handles count]);
    self.sampleTableView.delegate = self;
    self.sampleTableView.dataSource = self;
}

-(void)loadDataFromFirebase
{
    Firebase* listRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://wheresthatfoodtruck.firebaseIO.com/foodtrucks"];
    [listRef observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value);
        [handles addObject:snapshot.value];
    }];
}
```

Handles prints out the Item numbers, but if I remove that test data, [Handles count] becomes zero and the loading of the UITableView is faster then getting the data from Firebase. Much appreciated - I really like Firebase, its a great platform and I hope I can get past this issue.

Comment: Where are you updating your table? as a quick fix try adding: `[weakSelf.sampleTableView reloadData]` at the end of the block (`weakSelf` should be defined outside the block as `__block __weak id weakSelf = self;`

Comment: as of now, i'm just pulling down the json data, I tried calling [simpleTableView reloadData] after each snapshot.value call but no luck. What does the weak type do?

Comment: I have an error where the sampleTableView isn't an attribute of weakSelf. Isn't weakSelf a copy of self and therefor has access to all synthesized properties?

Comment: In other news, adding reloadData after the firebase block didn't fix anything. I see the data being pulled down in the logs, just not pushed to the table.

Comment: change the `weakSelf` type from `id` to the type of class of self to avoid the error

Comment: you also need to implement the table datasource methods: [see here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). in addition, make the handles array a strong property of self

Comment: Adding the reloadData after the Firebase block won't help; since that section of code is asynchronous, there's a race condition between the data showing up and the reload actually taking effect. You should move the reloadData inside the block itself. That has the same net effect as the work around you described in the answer below. Take a look at this example code: https://github.com/firebase/firechat-ios/blob/master/Firechat/ViewController.m — it's very similar to the scenario you're describing (note the reloadData inside the block @ line # 42).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. the firebase pulldown now beats the table most of the time, but occasionally I get a blank table that populates later. hmm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Firebase you have to keep in mind that all code (and, in particular, the blocks for the realtime updates) is asynchronously. For example, in the original question's comments as well as in the work-around answer, code like this:

```
[self loadDataFromFirebase];
[self.sampleTableView reloadData];
```

... can't be read from top to bottom; there will be a **race condition** between the data being populated (or views being updated) in the asynchronous blocks and the `reloadData` being called; maybe the cell connection is spotty, or GCD is optimizing for one thing over the other, and so on.

The second thing to keep in mind with Firebase is that for events like `child_added` there might not ever be any notion of "complete" — it's entirely possible for data to continually be shifting and updating; again, when would one expect `reloadData` to get called? Right away? After the first child? Last child? The implications of this are that if new data is added, even the work-around is going to yield behavior you're probably not expecting (i.e. it'll appear as if data isn't showing up because `reloadData` will never get called again.)

One approach you can take here would be to directly update your views as the data changes; so, your block would then look like:

```
[listRef observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
  NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value);
  [handles addObject:snapshot.value];
  [self.sampleTableView reloadData];
}];
```

Another approach might be to use Firebase to exclusively update your internal models and use the regular Objective-C approaches (KVO, Notifications, MVC, etc) to separate your data and view concerns to rerender views outside of direct changes to your models.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Rather then trying to query the database in viewDidLoad, in which case the view already came up as a frame, I moved the query to the time the nib was loaded but before the frame became visible. Here's the code, expanded upon:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    //link the CloudViewController with its View
    NSBundle *appBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    self = [super initWithNibName:@"FoodTruckViewController" bundle:appBundle];
    if (self) {
        self.sampleTableView.delegate = self;
        self.sampleTableView.dataSource = self;
        [self loadDataFromFirebase];
        [self.sampleTableView reloadData];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.sampleTableView reloadData];
}

-(void)loadDataFromFirebase
{
    handles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Firebase* listRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://wheresthatfoodtruck.firebaseIO.com/foodtrucks"];
    [listRef observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value);
        [handles addObject:snapshot.value];
    }];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [handles count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
[cell.textLabel setText:[handles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

@end
```

This version of the code populates the table before it becomes visible, but won't update from changes to the table in real time. I think the next step will be to make a call to the ChildChanged function form firebase in the viewDidLoad method to keep updates of any changes on the firebase side.

Comment: This work-around still contains race conditions between the events being triggered from Firebase and the views being update. There is no guarantee that the views will get updated "after" the data is loaded from Firebase unless you update the views *inside* the blocks.

Comment: sorry for the lag, I fixed that from your other responses to my questions. I thinkI just now need to adda  loading bar for the lag between mobile device and server.