# In Firebase, retrieved data doesn't get out from the .observeEventType method

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I defined a class in a project, to manage my database set up in Firebase. The following is what I've done with the class so far.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class db{
    class func getPrim() -> [String]{
        var ret = [String]()

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        ref.child("bunya1").observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: {
            s in

            ret = s.value! as! [String]

        })

        print("ret: \(ret)")
        return ret
    }
}
```

And the method is called in a `print()` method, like `print(db.getPrim())`. But what the console(or terminal? anyway the screen on the bottom of xcode..) says is only an empty array. I embraced the statement above with `print("-----------------------")`.

```
-----------------------
ret: []
[]
-----------------------
2016-09-07 20:23:08.808 이모저모[36962:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2016-09-07 20:23:08.815 이모저모[36962:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
```

Seems like `ret` in `.observeEventType()` method does not take its value out of the method block. As far as I know the data is supposed to be kept.. Can anyone give me a hint? I still don't understand how the code block as a method parameter works. Thnx!!

Comment: I wrote `print("ret: \(ret)")` right below the assigning statement `ret = s.value! as! [String]`. This one was printed a couple of seconds after the console messages I posted showed up.

Comment: All firebase operations are by definition asynchronous. So by the the time your print statements are called the data from firebase hasnt been fetched yet.

Comment: @AndréKool post it as answer

Comment: @AndréKool can you tell me about that in detail a little bit more please

Answer (score 3):

All firebase operations are by definition asynchronous which means your program doesn't wait for the data from firebase before going to the next statement in your code. So by the the time your print statements are called the data from firebase hasnt been fetched yet.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16026012/4916627) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

André (and the link to Vikrum's answer) are indeed why this is happening. But it's usually easiest to understand if you add a few log statements to your code:

```
class func getPrim() -> [String]{
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    print("Before observer");
    ref.child("bunya1").observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: {
        s in

        print("In observer block");

    })
    print("After observer");

    return "..."
}
```

When you run this code, the logging will be in this order:

> Before observer
>
> After observer
>
> In observer callback

This is probably not the order in which you expected them to appear. But it definitely explains why your returning an empty array in your snippet. If the code inside the block hasn't run yet, the item hasn't been added to the array yet.

The reason this order is inverted is as André and Vikrum say: the call to Firebase happens asynchronously. Since it can take some time (especially if this is the first time you're accessing the database), the Swift code continues executing to ensure the app stays responsive. Once the data comes back from Firebase, your block is called (for that reason it's sometimes referred to as a "callback") and you get the data.

Comment: Thank you! Then should I use `sleep()` method or something to wait for the `.observeEventType()` to finish executing?

Comment: Nope. You should move away from the "first do this, then do that" thinking and instead adopt a "if this happens, I'll do that in response" mindset. See Vikrum's answer that André linked to for an example of that.